# Regular Expression

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a data in a table as below in Column_01

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdSgg.png)

```
Column_01

abcded 01 isdnskdf 635 sjdsdf                          0000120
01 isdnskdf 635 sjdsdf                          0000220
test 002                                                        0000780
```

Expected result

```
Column_01

abcded 01 isdnskdf 635 sjdsdf                       
01 isdnskdf 635 sjdsdf                        
test 002
```

Comment: OK what have you attempted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you want to strip off trailing digits and preceding spaces

```
RegExp_Substr(col, '(.*?)(?= +\d+$)')  -- returns NULL when no trailing digits and preceding spaces

RegExp_Replace(col, ' +\d+$') -- returns full string when no trailing digits and preceding spaces
```